# Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture (C# WinForm Images in Resource File)

Tags: c#, winforms

I added three images to a file called Resource1.resx.  I also added one string just for test purposes. I'm getting this error on either the GetString or the GetObject(image-name).

> {"Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   \"Resource1.resources\" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly
>   \"TFBIC.RCT.Monitor\" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies
>   required are loadable and fully
>   signed."}

```
    // get initial images 
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(
    "Resource1",System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;


string strTest = rm.GetString("String1");  // just testing 

Bitmap bmCircleGreen = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("circleGreen");      
Bitmap bmCircleYellow = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("circleYellow");      
Bitmap bmCircleRed = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("circleRed");
```

My form is the first class in my project (I've already seen that error).
I assigned a strong-key to my project to no avail.
Not sure what else to try.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11384535/1257607) solved the problem for me! `GetGlobalResourceObject`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you remembered to include the  default namespace/folder when you reference the resource?

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("DefaultNamespace.Folder.ResourceName");
```

If you are unsure of the correct name, load the assembly in Reflector and browse down to see what it is.

Comment: It wasn't a concept of "remembering" but "knowing" <grin>. I never saw the namespace on any of the examples I had found.

Comment: You should also be able to get it strongly typed like nobugz mentions in a static manner: FolderName.ResourceFileName.YourResourceName

Answer (score 3):

The 1st argument is wrong.  But, there is already a ResourceManager created for you.  You can see its code: in the Solution Explorer window open the Properties node, open the Resources.resx node and double-click the Resources.Designer.cs file.

You'll get its instance with `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager`.  If you added the bitmaps with Project + Properties, Resources tab (strongly recommended), you can just refer to the property by the name you gave it.  Like `Properties.Resources.circleGreen`.  Do beware that you get a *new* image object each time you use the property, you may need to copy it to a variable if you use it more than once.

Comment: I found this: internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager.  Is that what you were talking about.  Not sure how to use it.  Since it's static, I tried "ResourceManager.getObject"... but that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I read your post again, it worked: 
        Bitmap bmCircleGreen = (Bitmap)  Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("circleGreen");

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. adding "DefaultNameSpace." ("BusinessLogic" is the default namespace in my case) before resourcefileName in following line resolved my problem

```
 public static ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(string.Concat("BusinessLogic." , Constants.Common.ResourceFileName), Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today on a VS-designer-built winform. I had added an image to an item of a menuStrip:

```
this->menuitemFileSettings->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>
  (resources->GetObject(L"menuitemFileSettings.Image")));
```

Since then the same error came up. Testing with images on other controls was the same.

- Based on [MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318603), the Form class must be the first in the code.
  This was was fine in my code.
- The resouces file also has the same name (frmMain.resx) as the winforms class (frmMain).
- Checking the created exe using ILSpy, I even found the image resource in the file. Something I retrospectively don't really understand.
- I am not using any localization.
- I created a new winform, copied all relevant parts there, same failure.

Somehow I finally stumbled over the **"Managed Resources"** entry in the project settings. The setting **"resource file name"** has the (default) value `$(IntDir)\$(RootNamespace).$(InputName).resources`... which is correct, but when I realized that the **path contains the name of the namespace**, I checked the namespace and found, that I had changed it (from NS_Winform to NS_assemblies) for easier import of the assemblies.

Changed it back, working fine now. :-)
But I still don't understand, how the resources content
 1) was included into the exe despite the wrong namespace, and
 2) not found then although included.

Comment: Thanks, due to age of this question, I'm no longer working on that project and cannot validate.

Comment: I was pretty much aware of that. I added my answer also to help other users.