# Initialize ResourceManager dynamically

Tags: asp.net, .net, resx, resource-files

I have this function and it works fine to get a translated value from this specific resource file called *OkayMessages*.

```
public static string GetResourceString(string resourceKey){
  ResourceManager resourceManager = Resources.OkayMessages.ResourceManager;
  return resourceManager.GetString(resourceKey);
}
```

But i have more than 1 resource file and i want this function to get values from those files as well.. Only, i'm having trouble with dynamically/programmatically selecting the right resource(manager). 
I have tried to use the code below, and some variants to that, but i always get an error.

```
public static string GetResourceString(string resourceFile, string resourceKey){
  ResourceManager resourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources." + resourceFile, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
  return resourceManager.GetString(resourceKey);
}
```

The error i got most of the times was: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "Resources.OkayMessages.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly..

**Update:** I'm using the \App_GlobalResources\ folder for my resource files, and it seems that this is the problem. When i place a resource file in the root of my project, i can initialize a ResourceManager without problems.

Comment: So the underlying problem here is that resources in the App_GlobalResources folder get compiled into their own assembly (App_GlobalResources).  The GetGlobalResourceObject method knows to use the correct assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching in the wrong direction for a while, I just found the most simple answer to this problem. It turns out that there is a method called `GetGlobalResourceObject`.

So in my case I'm now using this line of code which does all:

```
GetGlobalResourceObject("OkayMessages", "PasswordChanged").ToString();
```

Comment: Were you able to do this using files named Resources.OkayMessages (like your original example implies), or did you name it just "OkayMessages"?  To get it working I had to have no periods in the file name because it kept thinking that the period was the speration point for the localization.

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5.aspx) and you'll find that you need to specify correct namespace of the resource. That's your problem. Here is working example if OkayResources.resx resides in project root folder:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {

        public _Default()
        {
            var result = GetResourceString("OkayResources", "SomeKey");
        }

        private static string GetResourceString(string resourceFileName, string key)
        {
            var resourceName = "WebApplication1." + resourceFileName;
            var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(resourceName, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            return resourceManager.GetString(key);
        }
    }
}
```

If you put your resource file into Resources folder you'll have to update resource namespace:

```
var resourceName = "WebApplication1.Resources." + resourceFileName;
```

Comment: I'm still getting that same error. I'm using the \App_GlobalResources\ folder and because of that, my resource files reside in the namespace Resources. Would that make a difference?

Comment: In other parts of my code, i normally call a resource string like this Resources.OkayMessages.UserLoggedIn

Comment: I have updated my question with some findings after playing around with your solution. The problem seems to be the use of the \App_GlobalResources\ folder.

Comment: App_GlobalResources is not an issue itself. You have to update namespace. In your case it will be `YourDefaultNamespace.App_GlobalResources.FileName`. So, I believe my answer is correct.

Comment: I just tried this, and some variations, but still the same error. The good thing is, that it did make me search in some different directions, and i found the solution. I'll write an answer for it.